# Why isn't it an error to provide a default value that can't be used?

Tags: typescript

Beginner's question... In the example below, the `= 42` should never have an effect:

```js
class Example {
  foo({
    x = 42
  }: {
    x: number
  }) {
    
  }
}
```

Why does this not raise an error in typescript? Shouldn't either the `= 42` be removed, or the declaration be changed to `x?: number`?

Comment: I agree that it would be weird to do this intentionally, but there are plenty of constructs like `function foo(x: number) { x ??= 42; }` where no-op/unusable code isn't explicitly marked as an error.  Not sure if there's any canonical answer for the particular one you've raised though; it could be that nobody has cared enough to check for it.

Comment: I'm finding all kinds of fun issues in GitHub having to do with types of destructured assignments with default values, but nothing that seems applicable here.  I don't think I can find an answer to this question.  If you really think this is a problem you might want to file an issue about it, if only to get someone to say "this is how we want it to be, because XYZ reason".  Not sure.

Comment: Kind of a messy interpretation, but I feel like if you consider it in terms of subtypes, any type `T` is usable in any places that expect a `Partial<T>` (excluding mutation, but TypeScript's variance issues are well known).

In the example, if you separate the function definition from its typing (say you were typing an existing JS codebase), you're basically just being more specific than you need to be--the function can handle an optional `x`, but you're typing it as requiring `x` regardless, which is totally OK.

Comment: @jcalz: Thanks. I have opened https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43040

Comment: @y2bd you are correct that there can be a different treatment for unreachable code due to javascript itself, or due to type annotations. I opened https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/issues/1604 to be sure. In all cases, default arguments are not part of the typing, and there's clearly an error.